# How to put multiple text parameter on the flutter (dart)?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have code like this on the flutter, I need to put parameters data like icon and text, but I got error when put two text, how I can put two type same parameter?

```
new myCard(icon: Icons.home, text: 'Home', text: '234')
```

Comment: Add error message to the question.

Comment: It's usually better to tell us the final goal of what you're trying to achieve, this isn't usual. Is there a specified amount of text variables you want to pass? (e.g. first text for title, second text for subtitle, third text for description). Or do you want to receive any amount of strings to concatenate those? Also, it's impossible to use the same variable name.

Comment: [dart] The argument for the named parameter 'text' was already specified. [duplicate_named_argument]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same names for multiple parameters, because they worklike variables for the constructor/method.

What you have to do is create multiple parameters for every text you need. For instance: if you need a title, create a `title` parameter, for a subtitle, create a `subtitle` parameter, instead of trying to use title twice.

Another way would be to pass an array of strings if you'll use them together, like to generate a string (check the example below). But don't use it if you want different strings in different places, it wouldn't be a good practice.

Check out this example:

```
void main(){
  print( new Test(title: "Home", description: "The home page", textList: ["a", "list", "of", "strings"]) );
}

class Test {
  String title;
  String description;
  List<String> textList;

  Test({String this.title, String this.description,
        List<String> this.textList});

  @override
  String toString() => "Title: " + title + "\nDescription: "
    + description + "\nText list together: " + textList.join(" ");
}
```

(copy and paste the code [in the Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) if you want to test it, it simply creates and outputs a test class that receives two string parameters and a list of strings)

Comment: @Ashta you're welcome :) Since it helped, please mark this as accepted answer, by click the tick under the voting option on my answer.